# how to get rid of expect: spawn id exp7 not open

Tags: linux, expect

I have a expect script that spawn a process. The process ends quickly and sometimes it takes few seconds. It is a SQL query.
I have tried different things at the end of the script but still get the error below sometimes

expect: spawn id exp7 not open

Things tried:
1. interact
2. expect eof
3. exp_continue
4. expect eof
   catch wait result

What is the fool proof way to let the process and then exit expect script?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect
###exp_internal -f debug_info.log 0;
set username [lindex $argv 0]
set firstname [lindex $argv 1]
set lastname [lindex $argv 2]
set mypassword [lindex $argv 3]
set userpassword [lindex $argv 4]
set LOG_FILE [open /home/applusr/e291505/logs/ADD.log a]
set today [ exec /bin/date +%Y-%m-%d-%T]
set ::env(sec) /home/root/admin
puts $LOG_FILE "\n------------------ADD_SCRIPT - $today----$username--$firstname--$lastname--$env(sec)-"
close $LOG_FILE
set timeout 10
log_user 0
log_file -a /home/applusr/e291505/logs/ADD.log
spawn $env(sec)/add.mims.user $username "$firstname $lastname"
set addID $spawn_id
expect  "e291505's Password:*" { send "$mypassword\n" }
expect  "$username's New password:*" { send "$userpassword\n" }
expect  "Enter the new password again:*" { send "$userpassword\n" }
expect  "Password:" { sleep 1; send "$mypassword\n" }
##interact
```

Comment: Can't help you without seeing your code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks. Updated my question with code.

Comment: In this code, you are expecting to spawned process to give you 4 password prompts. Is that right? Does the process actually only ask for the first three?

Comment: Right, expecting spawned process to ask for 4 password. The process ask for all 4. I had to add sleep because the 4th password was getting printed in the log_file

Comment: The last line should be `expect eof` -- if you get "spawn id not open" every now and then, then the spawned program died too early: check the log.

Comment: @glennjackman You are right, the 4th password is asked optionally. What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you handle things to conditionally expect:

```
spawn $env(sec)/add.mims.user $username "$firstname $lastname"
set addID $spawn_id
expect  "e291505's Password:*"
send -- "$mypassword\n"
expect  "$username's New password:*" 
send -- "$userpassword\n"
expect  "Enter the new password again:*"
send -- "$userpassword\n"
expect {
    "Password:" { send -- "$mypassword\n"; exp_continue }
    eof
}
```

The last expect command will find that password prompt or the end of the process, whichever happens first. If the password prompt is seen, the `exp_continue` command "loops" within that expect command so that you keep waiting to see eof.

Note that I tweaked the `send` commands: you are now protected from any of the passwords starting with a hyphen.